# How do i store output of the function into an array

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

**DATA SET file name "demo.txt"**

```
ID|SAL|COL|PER|TAG|GER
1"|"1.11"|"2.22"|"1.1"|"2.2"|D"
2"|"1.234"|"3.234"|"2.2222"|"2.34"|"B"
3"|"1.234"|"35.23"|"3.2"|"2.34"|"A"
```

*I have created a function which will automatically calculate decimal column sum below is the function
I am calling that function in main.sh script*

```
demo()
{
FILE_NAME="$1"
COLUMN_NAME="$2"

alpha=( $(awk -F"|" 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if ($i ~ /'$COLUMN_NAME'/){print i;}}}' $FILE_NAME) )

for each in "${alpha[@]}"
do
   awk -F'"?\\|"?' '{T+=$('$each')} END { printf "%.2f\n", T }' $FILE_NAME  
done

}
```

**Script : main.sh**

*#function called in main.sh script*

```
demo demo.txt 'SAL|COL|PER|TAG'
```

issue is how do i get the output into an array

**below is the output i am getting need to store into array1**

```
3.57 40.68 6.52 6.88
```

**second array is this below output getting from another program**

```
array2={3.57 40.68 6.52 6.88}
```

**so that I can match the array1 with array 2 position value

```
array1[0] with array2[0] 
array1[1] with array2[1] 
array1[2] with array2[2] 
array1[3] with array2[3]
```

*if all succeed should display success status as YES*

**i have solution which is partially working ... help me with some solution** 
**so that i can store each value of an array to array1**

```
FILE_NAME="$1"
COLUMN_NAME="$2"

alpha=( $(awk -F"|" 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if ($i ~ /'$COLUMN_NAME'/){print i;}}}' $FILE_NAME) )

declare -a array=();

for each in "${alpha[@]}"
do
        #var=($(awk -F'"?\\|"?' '{T+=$('$each')} END { printf "%.2f\n", T }' $FILE_NAME))
        mapfile -t array <<< "$(awk -F'"?\\|"?' '{T+=$('$each')} END { printf "%.2f\n", T }' $FILE_NAME)"
        #awk -F'"?\\|"?' '{T+=$('$each')} END { printf "%.2f\n", T }' $FILE_NAME
done

echo "${array[@]}"
```

Comment: Does your input file not contain the " at the end and at the beginning of each row?

Comment: @aborruso ... specifically i am targeting on specific column sum where in my case the file data is in that format which is fixed ..my code is able to print sum of SAL COST PER TAG ... but the problem is the printed output i want to store into array 1 so that i can match array1 first with first value of array2 ..and so on ... if all value in array1 match with array 2 then depending on success my another script should run otherwise it should exit by saying data does not match

Comment: @aborruso .. this entire process should be done without creating a third file that why i am targeting to compare output of demo function with output of array2 ... is their any another approach to do kindly share without creating file can be compare on success my another script should run or exit by saying data does not match

Comment: @Kusalananda  can you look into this above post ... and provide me your solution how to do it ?

Comment: @aborruso  .. updated my question with new data set .. please provide me your solution

Comment: `array2={3.57 40.68 6.52 6.88}` it's not a bash array. Am I wrong? You could compare all as string

Comment: @aborruso .. can you tell me how do i get demo function values and store in array1

Comment: @aborruso .. updated the question with partially working solution can you be able to look into it and provide your valuable input with solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your partly working solution is you store the single value from the sum of one column into the entire array every time, which deletes the previous values.

The solution is to stuff the values into the array one by one, rather than using the mapfile command which requires all the values on one input line:

```
FILE_NAME="$1"
COLUMN_NAME="$2"

alpha=( $(awk -F"|" 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if ($i ~ /'$COLUMN_NAME'/){print i;}}}' $FILE_NAME) )

declare -a array=()

n=0

for each in "${alpha[@]}"
do
        array[n]="$(awk -F'"?\\|"?' '{T+=$('$each')} END { printf "%.2f\n", T }' $FILE_NAME)"
        ((n=n+1))
done

echo "${array[@]}"
```

Running this gives:

```
$ bash test.sh demo.txt 'SAL|COL|PER|TAG'
3.58 40.68 6.52 6.88
```

Comment: thank you !!! bro you are awesome

Comment: `bash` knows how to append to an array: `array+=( "$( awk ... )" )`. Note also that the `awk` code contains a serious code injection vulnerability. Just set your `$COLUMN_NAME` value to something that ends the regular expression, and then inject whatever code you want.

Answer (score 0):

To get the output of `demo` into an array you could use Command Substitution

```
declare -a array1=( $(demo) )
```

and replace the call to `demo` within your script with the line above.

PS: If the input file has a fixed (and pre-defined) number of columns it might be easier to sum the columns directly into the array elements (and probably faster because you won't need to read `$FILENAME` #columns + 1 times).

Comment: i want to store each ouput of an array which is running to array1

Comment: i have updated the partially running solution will you able to add some working solution to it

Comment: @genip26057 My answer solves the "can you tell me how do i get demo function values and store in array1" problem you mention in the comments above, just replace the current call to `demo` within the script with the line from my answer. If this is not what you want please update the question, especially the "below is the output i am getting need to store into array1" part.