# assign output of awk command to array linux

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

I have a scenario where I want to store values of command run output to array

I have a dat set like below

```
ID|SAL|COST|PER|TAG
1"|"10.1"|"12.22"|"10.1"|"A" 
2"|"10.223"|"12.333"|"10.1"|"B"
```

after running the below command I am getting sum of column output as

```
awk -F"|" 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if ($i ~ /SAL|COST/){print i;}}}' demo.txt

2
3
```

But the issue is I want the generated output need to be stored in array
I am using below approach not working using `mapfile -t`

```
mapfile -t array < <(awk -F"|" 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if ($i ~ /SAL|COST/){print i;}}}' demo.txt)
```

when I print `echo "${array[@]}"` it gives me only one output value not all the value

```
output:
3
```

**need all the output values need to be printed. when I echo array **

```
2
3
```

Comment: The awk command produces the output '2 3' for me when run on your sample data

Comment: sorry bro i forgot to change output … have change the output can you pass output values to an array and display all values of an array

Comment: When I run your mapfile command and then your echo command, I get "2 3" as expected

Comment: I think your real problem is your awk command. It is printing the column numbers of the SAL and COST columns, not the actual values.

Comment: @nickcrabtree  can you share your code pls

Comment: How is this question different from your most recent question at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/559967/116858 ?   Consider sitting down and actually think about what it is you are trying do, and then write a question about how to solve that problem.  It looks to me that you are asking a series of questions that are all about similar things and that, when taken together, may not solve your actual problem in an optimal way.  Also, your awk code sums no columns.

Comment: @nickcrabtree  … this is the actual scenario i am working on can you provide you solution  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/559967/how-do-i-store-output-of-the-function-into-an-array  … i need to output the sum values into an array … its a challenging thing i am facing since 2 days not able to get it

Comment: `mapfile -t array < <(awk -F"|" 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if ($i ~ /SAL|COST/){print i;}}}' demo.txt)`  and `echo "${array[@]}"` prints `2 3`

Answer (score 0):

From the bash man page:

> Arrays  are  assigned  to using compound assignments of the form name=(value1 ... valuen)

So you would assign it like this:

```
myarray=( $(awk -F"|" 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if ($i ~ /SAL|COST/){print i;}}}' demo.txt) )
```

Then the following:

```
echo ${myarray[@]}
echo "first: ${myarray[0]}"
echo "second: ${myarray[1]}"
```

Should give this output:

```
2 3
first: 2
second: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Fully supporting what Kusalananda said in his comment, let me add that your apparent problem can be solved with a slight modification to your commands:

```
$ IFS=$'\n'
$ echo "${array[*]}"
2
3
```